# KeyError at /category/news.html 'request' when trying to add category

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

So I am trying to add categories to articles, but I get a KeyError. This is my model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)
    slug        = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_blog_category', None, { 'slug': self.slug })
```

And this my view and urls:

```
def view_category(request, slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    return render_to_response('news/view_category.html', {'category': category,'posts': Article.objects.filter(category=category)[:5]})
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^news/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', ArticleView.as_view() , name='view_blog_post'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', view_category, name='view_blog_category'),
]
```

When I go to a category I added through django admin I get a `KeyError at /category/news.html 'request'` and it shows a error when rendering a inclusion tag. (A sidebar) If I remove this inclusion tag the KeyError goes away. But on all other pages the inclusion tag is working just fine. Only on this category page not. What is the problem?

I think there is something wrong with my url but I can't seem to find the problem.

The traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/category/news.html

Django Version: 1.11
Python Version: 3.6.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'home',
 'news',
 'dynamic_scraper',
 'taggit']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/src/cryptoupdate/home/templates/header.html, error at line 41
   request   31 :       <i class="close-icn ion-close"></i>
   32 :     </a>
   33 :     <div class="src-form">
   34 :       <form>
   35 :         <input type="text" placeholder="Search here">
   36 :         <button type="submit"><i class="ion-search"></i></a></button>
   37 :       </form>
   38 :     </div><!-- src-form -->
   39 : 
   40 :     <a class="menu-nav-icon" data-menu="#main-menu" href="#"><i class="ion-navicon"></i></a>
   41 :      {% header_menu %} 
   42 :     <div class="clearfix"></div>
   43 :   </div><!-- container -->
   44 : </header>
   45 : 

Traceback:

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/src/cryptoupdate/news/views.py" in view_category
  20.     return render_to_response('news/view_category.html', {'category': category,'posts': Article.objects.all()})

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render_to_response
  21.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, using=using)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  216.                 return template.render(context)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                 return self._render(context)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/library.py" in render
  225.         _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/src/cryptoupdate/home/templatetags/header_menu.py" in header_menu
  11.         'request': context['request'],

File "/Users/rafrasenberg/cryptoupdate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in __getitem__
  87.         raise KeyError(key)

Exception Type: KeyError at /category/news.html
Exception Value: 'request'
```

The template tag after editing

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def header_menu(context):
    return {
        'header_menu': MenuItem.objects.all(),
        'request': context['request'],
    }
```

Comment: can you please show the traceback?

Comment: Updated now with the traceback included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render_to_response` doesn't pass the request. You should use `render` instead.

```
return render(request, 'news/view_category.html', ...)
```

But it's not clear why you are referencing the request in the tag code anyway. You don't use it there, si what's the point of getting it from the context only to pass it straight back?

Comment: @RafRasenberg please accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

the bug is here:

```
'request': context['request']
```

in your `header_menu` template tag. You should change template tag decorator to:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def header_menu(context):
   # your template tag code
```

so that it can use the context passed by views

Comment: I just added the template tag to the post. Using your method, still getting the KeyError